# regex: allow/deny characters by Language

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I have tow text field, the first must exclude the arabic characters ([\u0600-\u06FF0-9]) and the second must exclude the latin characters.
I need help to find these two patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can match a full unicode range with the unicode blocks:

- `\p{InArabic}` (U+0600–U+06FF)
- `\p{InBasic_Latin}` (U+0000–U+007F)

Or use scripts:

- `\p{Arabic}`
- `\p{Latin}`

Read here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

*Edit:* Javascript does not support these tools.
Use basic range instead:

- `[\u0600-\u06FF]` Arabic
- `[\u0000-\u007F]` Latin